# Trayicon missing when restart Windows 7

Tags: windows, dos, windows-7-x64, trayicon

When restart Windows, some tray icons were missing.
Is there a command to redraw trayIcon or prevent they missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these DOS command:

```
%windir%\system32\taskkill.exe /IM explorer.exe /F
start %windir%\explorer.exe
```

Or make a batch file.